# CSS style not getting applied: Head First HTML Example

Tags: html, css

I just started reading HeadFirst HTML and CSS book. In the following example code in the book, the CSS styling in HTML code is not getting applied when I view it in IE/Firefox/Chrome.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Starbuzz Coffee</title>
<style type=”text/css”>
body {
background-color: #d2b48c;
margin-left: 20%;
margin-right: 20%;
border: 1px dotted gray;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Starbuzz Coffee Beverages</h1>
<h2>House Blend, $1.49</h2>
<p>A smooth, mild blend of coffees from Mexico, Bolivia and
Guatemala.</p>
<h2>Mocha Caffe Latte, $2.35</h2>
<p>Espresso, steamed milk and chocolate syrup.</p>
<h2>Cappuccino, $1.89</h2>
<p>A mixture of espresso, steamed milk and milk foam.</p>
<h2>Chai Tea, $1.85</h2>
<p>A spicy drink made with black tea, spices, milk and honey.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you please comment why it's not working as expected. Though I downloaded a file index.html from internet with same code as above and it was giving expected output.

Thanks,

Comment: `<style type=”text/css”>` -->`<style type="text/css">`

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `type=”text/css”` it needs to be `type="text/css"`.

Attribute values are usually delimited with *U+0022 : QUOTATION MARK* characters. There are other valid options, but you are using *U+201D : RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK* which isn't one of them.

A [validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/) would have picked this up.

Your problem may have been caused by using a word processor to write code. Use a text editor (such as Sublime Text, Atom, or Brackets).

Comment: Thanks Quentin, CSS style is taking effect after changing quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: Go into Preferences. From there, look under the Tab "New Document" and make sure the box "Smart Quotes" is **UN**checked. Feel free to also uncheck other spelling autocorrecting since you're just starting out and need a plain text editor that won't mess with what you're writing.

P.S., Brackets is really good because it has an intuitive feel, but it works best with Google Chrome, so you may have to download that browser if you don't have it already. TextEdit on the other hand works fine with Safari if you're just starting out.

Comment: what are those steps for? and IDE? text editor? how does that solve the question?

Comment: The steps are to reformat the TextEdit app on a Mac. TextEdit has options that automatically edit your code, but if you don't want it to you can change the preferences.

Comment: how does it solve the question tho'? and why is this answer about TextEdit if the question makes no mention of it? this not really an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try opening tag just `< style >` instead of `< style type=”text/css” >` or `< style type="text/css" >`. Had the same problem, this one worked for me.